# How do I install Logkeys?

Tags: software-installation

I'm very new to Ubuntu and using 12.04.  I need help with logkeys and installing and the codes don't respond. I get this after I try installing:

```
Couldn't find package "lkl".  However, the following
packages contain "lkl" in their name:
  sinhala-font-lklug fonts-lklug-sinhala ttf-sinhala-lklug 
Couldn't find package "lkl".  However, the following
packages contain "lkl" in their name:
  sinhala-font-lklug fonts-lklug-sinhala ttf-sinhala-lklug 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Package lkl was only used for an (now) old release of Ubuntu. The [package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lkl) on launchpad shows only Hardy.

So if you want this you need to install [the source code from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkl/). Download it, open a console and extract the files from the archive. The following commands should install it:

- `cd lkl`
- `./configure`
- `make`
- `make check` (not required but it does some tests).
- `sudo make install`

to install the package program and you should have the command `lkl` on your system.